# How To make Date on HTML from File name (PNG)

Tags: javascript

I have an image file with the file name using (year_mounth_date.png)

I want each image displayed in HTML, the description below the image is the Date of the Month and Year in accordance with the image file name. How to make Javascript code to work.

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
 <input onchange='setImage(this)' type="range" min="0" max="8" value="0" step="1" id="myRange"
                        class="slider" />
                    <p class="text-slider"> <b>Value <span id="demo"></span></b></p>
            <img id='img_pic' src='img/2020_04_11.png' height="20" width="130" class="image" />
  </div>


 <script>
            var imgpic = document.getElementById('img_pic');
            var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
            var output = document.getElementById("demo");
            output.innerHTML = slider.value;
            slider.oninput = function () {
                output.innerHTML = this.value;
            }
            var img_array1 = ['img/2020_04_11.png', 'img/2020_04_12.png', 'img/2020_04_13.png'];
            function setImage(obj) {
                var value = obj.value;
                imgpic.src = img_array1[value];


            }

 <script>
```

Hot To make function code, File Name can be easier to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for that:

```
function getImage() {
    var d = new Date();
    return '/path/to/image/' + d.getFullYear() + '_' + d.getMonth() + '_' + d.getDay() + '.png' ;
}
```

Comment: if for tomorrow, "+d.getDay() +1" , Can it be added with the number 1 ?

Comment: `"+ (d.getDay() + 1) + "` - yes, just add parentheses around operation, otherwise it would be strings concatenation

Comment: any Question for you, look at my question. I found a problem to apply in my script about your answer : 


function getImage() {
    var d = new Date();
    return '/path/to/image/' + d.getFullYear() + '_' + d.getMonth() + '_' + d.getDay() + '.png' ;
}